# Improving Performance of this MiniMax with AlphaBeta Pruning

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I have the following implementation of a alpha beta minimax for an othello (reversi) game. I've fixed a few of it's problems from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243099/minimax-with-alpha-beta-pruning-for-othello-not-working-c) thread. This time I'd like to improve the performance of this function. It's taking a very long time with MAX_DEPTH = 8. What can be done to speed up the performance, while keeping the AI somewhat decent?

```
mm_out minimax(Grid& G, int alpha, int beta, Action& A, uint pn, uint depth, bool stage) {
    if (G.check_terminal_state() || depth == MAX_DEPTH) {
        return mm_out(A, G.get_utility(pn));
    }

    // add end game score total here

    set<Action> succ_temp = G.get_successors(pn);
    for (Action a : succ_temp) {
        Grid gt(G);
        a.evaluate(gt);
    }
    set<Action, action_greater> successors(succ_temp.begin(), succ_temp.end());

    // if no successor, that player passes
    if (successors.size()) {
        for (auto a = successors.begin(); a != successors.end(); ++a) {
            Grid gt(G);
            gt.do_move(pn, a->get_x(), a->get_y(), !PRINT_ERR);
            Action at = *a;
            mm_out mt = minimax(gt, alpha, beta, at, pn ^ 1, depth + 1, !stage);
            int temp = mt.val;
//          A = mt.best_move;

            if (stage == MINIMAX_MAX) {
                if (alpha < temp) {
                    alpha = temp;
                    A = *a;
                }
                if (alpha >= beta) {
                    return mm_out(A, beta);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (beta > temp) {
                    beta = temp;
                    A = *a;
                }
                if (alpha >= beta) {
                    return mm_out(A, alpha);
                }


}
    }
    return mm_out(A, (stage == MINIMAX_MAX) ? alpha : beta);
}
else {
    return mm_out(A, (stage == MINIMAX_MAX) ? (std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - 1) : (std::numeric_limits<int>::min() + 1));
}
```

}

Utility function:

```
int Grid::get_utility(uint pnum) const {
    if (pnum)
        return wcount - bcount;
    return bcount - wcount;
}
```

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should not contain code that isn't strictly needed (such as debug output). Please edit your question to remove it.

Comment: Done. Thanks for informing.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to speed up the performance of your search function. If you implement these techniques properly, they will cause very little harm to the accuracy of the algorithm while pruning many nodes.

- The first technique that you can implement are transposition table. Transposition tables store in a hashtable all previously visited nodes in your game search tree. Most game states, especially in a deep search, can be reaches through various transpositions, or orders of moves that resurt in the same final state. By storing previously searched game states, if you find a state already searched, you can use the data stored in the tables and stop deepening the search at that node. The standard technique to store game states in a hashtable is called Zobrist Hashing. Detailed information on the implementation of transposition tables is available on the web.
- The second thing your program should include is move ordering.This essentially means to examine moves not in the order you generate them, but in the order that seems most likely to produce an alpha beta cutoff (ie good moves first). Obviously you can't know which moves are best, but most moves can be ordered using a naive technique. For example, in Othello a move that is in a corner or edge should be examined first. Ordering moves should lead to more cutoffs and an increase in search speed. This poses zero loss to accuracy.
- You can also add opening books. Usually the opening moves take the longest to search, as the board is full of more possibilities.An opening book is a database that stores every possible move that can be made in the first few turns, and the best response to it., In Othello, with a low branching factor, this will be especially helpful in the opening game
- Probcut. Im not going to go into more detail here as this is a more advanced technique. However it has had good results with othello, so I figured I'd post this link.https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/ProbCut

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've done the 2nd since the time of my post, I've noticed a small but noticable speed increase. I'm going to take a look at the others.